# Use Grub to fix hard drive bootup

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, startup

**SSD** - `/dev/nvme0n1p1`

UUID - db81b2af-0d6d-4ad4-9db5-f68d2e36c079,

Partition Type - Linux (Bootable)

Contents - Ext4(v1.0 - Mounted at /media/ubuntu/.....

**3TB storage drive** - `/dev/sda1`

UUID - db81b2af-0d6d-4ad4-9db5-f68d2e36c079

Partition Type - Linux Filesystem

Contents Ext4(v1.0) - Not Mounted

---

I started with a clean install of Ubuntu Linux 19.04 on my SSD a couple days ago.

My second internal hard drive, 3TB storage drive was not clean installed. It had a bunch of data that was part of the previous W10 OS. I decided to wipe my 3TB drive and start clean because I was having too many problems trying to transfer permission from root to me and I was unable to write to the drive, just read.

After I wiped it, I restarted my computer and am having boot issues now. I suspect that I did a poor job at formatting my 3TB hard drive and that caused an unexpected issue. In my BIOS, my SSD ALWAYS boots first so I was surprised that this would become an issue.

I loaded ubuntu from a USB and ran the boot-repair report and here is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D3WQYFgzNW/

Not sure what to do from here, I just have a general sense of what might have caused the problem, but no real idea where to go to zoom in on the issue.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
Unless your 3TB drive was the boot drive, and rest of system is on SSD, just fixing grub will not normally be the fix. But best to see details to know issue or issues.

Comment: Maybe your second drive is the first drive to boot. Try changing the order on your BIOS settings.

Comment: BIOS or EFI? Boot with USB , attach your  SSD  and run update-grub. Reboot with both devices attached. Should get "grub" screen with boot device selection options.

Comment: @oldfred http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D3WQYFgzNW/ My 3TB is NOT the boot drive (at least not to my knowledge). 100% of the system SHOULD be on the SSD. At least that was my intention, I am a new linux user so I don't really know anything :D

Comment: I reformatted my post for better clarity and added the report

Comment: Boot-repair report says: ***The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of nvme0n1p1 into the MBRs of all disks (except live-disks)***

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix so....I should do the default repair then?

Comment: @EvanKim I always do the default repair without giving it a second thought. But I think you want to be more cautious and wait a day or two to check out other suggestions.

Comment: Boot-Repair default usually is ok, sometimes with multiple drives it does not make best choice. It will give an error if you do default as grub only installs correctly to gpt drives in BIOS  mode, if gpt drive has a tiny 1 or 2 MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag. But you have MBR on NVMe drive, so grub should install ok.But it looks like you have newer UEFI hardware and older BIOS/MBR configuration on NVMe drive. Run repair, ignore error on install to 3TB drive or use Advanced mode and just choose to install grub to NVMe drive. Be sure to boot in BIOS mode.

Comment: hmm I am not able to load the USB anymore...it says `Booting 'find /menu.list, /boot/grub/menu.lst, /grub/menu/lst`. I press ESC but it doesn't give me the option to load ubuntu anymore. I only have the former option, commandline, reboot, and halt. Do I need to reformat my USB???? I'm not even sure what could have possibly changed, all I did was run `boot-repair`

Comment: I try to enter `boot` in `grub>`, but I get `Kernel must be loaded before booting`

Comment: Alright, I reinstalled 19.04 Ubuntu on my USB via my laptop and I did the default repair (is it the same thing as auto repair????)...It didn't seem to fix the problem. I got black screen and then straight back to GRUB4DOS screen with `find /menu.lst....`, `commandline`, `reboot`, and `halt`. Back where I started...with the grub command line popping up after booting from USB

Comment: Could you add a picture of your BIOS boot options? If you don't know how to do it maybe we can guide you through the process.

Comment: Interesting. I re-installed ubuntu on the USB stick, did the boot-repair, and noticed that I was getting an error i nstalling grub because my SSD was full. I changed the reserve space to 0 to free up a precious 12GB and that allowed me to boot properly. However now I am confused why my hard drive is so full. I transferred about 150GB of files (it was over my capacity so I deleted the files, but it must not have deleted properly and is still filing up the SSD. 

Anyways I am back in now at least